# How can I make counter cache with complicated condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, counter-cache

**I migrated this to enable counter cache**

```
class AddUniquecodesCountToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :users, :uniquecodes_count, :integer, :default => 0

    User.reset_column_information
    User.all.each do |p|
      User.reset_counters(p.id, :uniquecodes)
    end
  end

  def down
    remove_column :users, :uniquecodes_count
  end

end
```

I'm usually fetching the number of uniquecodes the user has by this code

```
current_user.uniquecodes.joins(:community).merge(Community.not_deleted).order("uniquecodes.updated_at DESC").count.to_s
```

**models/community.rb**

```
....
def self.not_deleted
    where deleted_at: nil
end
....
```

The reason why I'm doing this is, there is possibility that community record could be deleted. So that I don't want to display uniquecodes once related community has deleted.

As you see my migration file, it just counts up or down whole number of uniquecodes whose `user_id` is related to particular user's id when the user create/delete uniquecode.

How can I add the condition that I wrote above in order to exclude the uniquecodes whose `community_id` is deleted (If deleted, deleted_at column will be filled with timestamp)